# how to make a process unstoppable?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, vb6

There are some process in the *Windows-Task-Manager* that you can't kill them in Non-Administrator users :

[image]

And even in Administrator users, when you try to kill them, you receive this below warning :

[image]

I want to know, is there any way to make another program's process like this? i.e if I want to write a program with *VB6* for example, is there any way to prevent the user to kill its process? (having this behavior, or a similar behavior that prevent stopping it)

Comment: [related](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx) and [related](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/20/10427187.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [flag programs as critial](https://github.com/jschicht/ProcessCritical). Doing this would bugcheck your system with [Bug Check 0xF4: CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you try to kill the process. This is how csrss.exe is flagged and this is why you see this meesage.

Comment: Is there any code-base solution? I mean "Can I wrote my program in a way that behave like this?" Assume that I don't want to use any third-party software.

Comment: @Abraham if you click on the first link provided, you can see a programmatical way to do it. Granted, it's using AutoIt language, but the program itself invoked system-standard DLLs, and such invocation is doable from any programming language; you just have to find how :)

Comment: @pepoluan Thank you :) I just was took a brief look. I read it again deeper.